# awk - how to extract a pattern

Tags: awk, gawk

Asking for instructions about using awk to extract text blocks with specific rows from a file.

The file has the following structure:

```
<Information>
<CID>_whole_number_A_</CID>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
<string>_PATTERN_A_</string>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
</Information>
<Information>
<CID>_whole_number_B_</CID>
<string>_PATTERN_B_</string>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
<string>_text_that_is_not_useful_</string>
</Information>
```

Would like to awk to send the following pattern to a new file.

```
<Information>
<CID>_whole_number_A_</CID>
<string>_PATTERN_A_</string>
</Information>
<Information>
<CID>_whole_number_B_</CID>
<string>_PATTERN_B_</string>
</Information>
```

Notes about the data:

- The file has 300,000+ CID items; each identified with a unique whole
  number.
- The PATTERNs (_PATTERN_A_, _PATTERN_B_, etc.) have the format
  UNII-<10 characters>. For example: UNII-4J4Z8788N8 or UNII-12L95QD6KV.
- Not every CID has a UNII.

Notes about my environment:

- Am working under Windows 7 and using the GnuWin32 utilities

So, rephrasing in English:

> in FILE_1
>
> find every CID that has a UNII
>
> send the filtered results to FILE_2

Thanks in advance for instructions.

========================================================================

OK, I'm doing something wrong.

In my first implementation, the program only returns "record starts" and "closing tag," i.e.:

```
<Information>
</Information>
```

Here is how I applied your instructions.

First, I'm running Windows so changed to FS="\r\n"

The first regular expression is UNII, so changed to /UNII/.

The second regular expression is CID, which you used in your instructions. I made no change there.

For the second instance of PATTERN, I changed to /UNII/.

Here is how my substitutions look:

```
BEGIN {
    RS="<Information>"
    FS="\r\n"
}
/UNII/ {
    print RS
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /CID/ || $i ~ /UNII/) {
            print $i
        }
    }
    print "</Information>"
}
```

Because I am using Windows, I use a full path to execute the GnuWin32 utilities and read/write data. So my .bat file looks like this:

```
C:\bin\awk -f C:\bin\script.awk < C:\Users\Owner\data\input_file.txt > C:\Users\Owner\data\output_file.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

=================================================================================
Here is sample data:

```
<Information>
    <CID>1</CID>
    <Synonym>Acetyl carnitine</Synonym>
    <Synonym>O-Acetyl-L-carnitine</Synonym>
    <Synonym>Ammonium, (3-carboxy-2-hydroxypropyl)trimethyl-, hydroxide, inner salt, acetate, DL-</Synonym>
    <Synonym>UNII-07OP6H4V4A</Synonym>
    <Synonym>_20+_more_</Synonym>
</Information>
<Information>
    <CID>10006</CID>
    <Synonym>HYDANTOIN</Synonym>
    <Synonym>UNII-I6208298TA</Synonym>
    <Synonym>53760_FLUKA</Synonym>
    <Synonym>NSC9226</Synonym>
    <Synonym>_20+_more_</Synonym>
</Information>
<Information>
    <CID>10007</CID>
    <Synonym>Lucofen SA</Synonym>
    <Synonym>461-78-9</Synonym>
    <Synonym>EINECS 207-314-9</Synonym>
    <Synonym>STK664067</Synonym>
    <Synonym>DEA No. 1645</Synonym>
    <Synonym>UNII-NHW07912O7</Synonym>
    <Synonym>CHEMBL1201269</Synonym>
    <Synonym>HMS1376E21</Synonym>
    <Synonym>_20+_more_</Synonym>
</Information>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should provide a good starting point:

```
BEGIN {
    RS="<Information>"
    FS="\n"
}
/UNII/ {
    print RS
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /CID/ || $i ~ /UNII/) {
            print $i
        }
    }
    print "</Information>"
}
```

Saving it to `script.awk` and running it on your sample input produces:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
<Information>
    <CID>1</CID>
    <Synonym>UNII-07OP6H4V4A</Synonym>
</Information>
<Information>
    <CID>10006</CID>
    <Synonym>UNII-I6208298TA</Synonym>
</Information>
<Information>
    <CID>10007</CID>
    <Synonym>UNII-NHW07912O7</Synonym>
</Information>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out this morning and get back to you if I encounter (user) errors.

Comment: Added additional questions to the responding instructions

Comment: It's hard to debug without the input file really, try stripping the script back, if only a single `<Information>` and `</Information>` is seen in the output file it would suggest the whole file is treated as one record i.e. does record separator `<Information>` match exactly, check for case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll post a data sample here in a few moments.

Comment: @JayGray please check your line endings. With the sample input and the modified script (with `FS="\n"`) I get the expected output, see edit.

Comment: OK - it was user error. The origin of the data file was Unix. When I look at the file on Windows, the editor (incorrectly) displays \r\n, but the real data has \n. Your solution is spot on - thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First, awk is completely the wrong tool for this. But the simplest way to do this with awk, is to suppress the lines you don't want (rather than selecting the ones you do want):

```
/Synonym/ && !/UNII/ { next }
{ print }
```

Comment: This is an over simplification and will fail for the case `Not every CID has a UNII.`